# No SDL2 keyboard events on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sdl, raspberry-pi, sdl-2

I'm trying to use SDL2 2.0.3 on the Raspberry Pi running the latest Raspbian, but my program does not receive any events from the keyboard. (The joystick and haptics work, and graphics work). Adding my user to the tty and input groups, or running the program as root, does not help. Are there additional configuration steps or packages that need to be installed on the Pi for SDL2 keyboard input to work?

(Once the program exits, the Raspberry Pi has to be reset for keyboard input to work at all on the device, although this could be because of my own failure to call SDL_Quit()?)

Comment: SDL uses udev to detect keyboards and evdev to get keyboard events directly from the kernel...if you are successfully using a joystick this means both systems work fine, so it could be a problem with your particular model of keyboard that SDL doesn't like? Feel free to file a bug with SDL's Bugzilla if indeed the problem is with the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Installing libudev-dev and rebuilding SDL2 made mouse and keyboard input work for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

Run `./configure` in the SDL2 directory and search for the line

```
Using libudev   : YES
```

Can't help you with failed keyboard input after program exit, sorry.